# How does git copy instruction in packfile to represent the offset which larges than 4GB?

Tags: git

Refer to this document: [pack-format](https://git-scm.com/docs/pack-format)

> The first seven bits in the first octet determines which of the next seven octets is present. If bit zero is set, offset1 is present. If bit one is set offset2 is present and so on.

And I found the code snippet in patch-delta.c:

```c
    while (data < top) {
        cmd = *data++;
        if (cmd & 0x80) {
            unsigned long cp_off = 0, cp_size = 0;
#define PARSE_CP_PARAM(bit, var, shift) do { \
            if (cmd & (bit)) { \
                if (data >= top) \
                    goto bad_length; \
                var |= ((unsigned) *data++ << (shift)); \
            } } while (0)
            PARSE_CP_PARAM(0x01, cp_off, 0);
            PARSE_CP_PARAM(0x02, cp_off, 8);
            PARSE_CP_PARAM(0x04, cp_off, 16);
            PARSE_CP_PARAM(0x08, cp_off, 24);
            PARSE_CP_PARAM(0x10, cp_size, 0);
            PARSE_CP_PARAM(0x20, cp_size, 8);
            PARSE_CP_PARAM(0x40, cp_size, 16);
#undef PARSE_CP_PARAM
            if (cp_size == 0) cp_size = 0x10000;
            if (unsigned_add_overflows(cp_off, cp_size) ||
                cp_off + cp_size > src_size ||
                cp_size > size)
                goto bad_length;
            memcpy(out, (char *) src_buf + cp_off, cp_size);
            out += cp_size;
            size -= cp_size;
        } else if (cmd) {
            if (cmd > size || cmd > top - data)
                goto bad_length;
            memcpy(out, data, cmd);
            out += cmd;
            data += cmd;
            size -= cmd;
```

So there is only four bytes to determine the offset of the source object, what about if the source object larges than 4GB ?

Comment: Please see my response below.  You *CAN* use Git pack objects to fetch arbitrarily large objects.  You *CAN'T* reliably expect a single object to always be able to exceed 2GB (32-bit signed int).  The alternative is to split the source into multiple, smaller pack objects.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What I understand from your response is that, git would never generates a copy instruction in packfile which its offset of the base object larges than 4GB, right?

Comment: Basically, I believe that's correct: yes.  Remember: "git" is a *protocol*.  Different client implementations (e.g. Tortoise Git) or different cloud services (e.g. GitHub or BitBucket) might do different things.   Please consider "upvoting" and/or "accepting" the answer, if you found it helpful.

Comment: @paulsm4 I am sorry I have no enough reputation to upvote your answer. The create_delta function in diff-delta.c seems to be the answer for my question, but I don't fully understand it. https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/diff-delta.c

Comment: @paulsm4: I wouldn't say that Git *is* a protocol, but it certainly *defines* (multiple) protocols. Someday there might be some for "large-object pack files" but probably not for a while yet. 

Answer (score 2):

Although the Git documentation doesn't specify a "maximum pack object size", 2GB is often a practical limit.  Here's an example: [Critical Error: Object too large, rejecting the pack. Max object size limit is 2,147,483,639 bytes.](https://tickets.dominodatalab.com/hc/en-us/articles/360058040352-Critical-Error-Object-too-large-rejecting-the-pack-Max-object-size-limit-is-2-147-483-639-bytes-)

If your repo has lots of "huge files", you might wish to consider setting `--max-pack-size=<n>`:

> https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pack-objects
>
> **--max-pack-size=n**
>
> In unusual scenarios, you may not be able to create files larger than
> a certain size on your filesystem, and this option can be used to tell
> the command to split the output packfile into multiple independent
> packfiles, each not larger than the given size. The size can be
> suffixed with "k", "m", or "g". The minimum size allowed is limited to
> 1 MiB. The default is unlimited, unless the config variable
> pack.packSizeLimit is set. Note that this option may result in a
> larger and slower repository; see the discussion in
> pack.packSizeLimit.

You can read futher details here:

> https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config
>
> **pack.packSizeLimit**
>
> The maximum size of a pack. This setting only affects packing to a
> file when repacking, i.e. the git:// protocol is unaffected. It can be
> overridden by the --max-pack-size option of git-repack[1]. Reaching
> this limit results in the creation of multiple packfiles.
>
> Note that this option is rarely useful, and may result in a larger
> total on-disk size (because Git will not store deltas between packs),
> as well as worse runtime performance (object lookup within multiple
> packs is slower than a single pack, and optimizations like
> reachability bitmaps cannot cope with multiple packs).
>
> If you need to actively run Git using smaller packfiles (e.g., because
> your filesystem does not support large files), this option may help.
> But if your goal is to transmit a packfile over a medium that supports
> limited sizes (e.g., removable media that cannot store the whole
> repository), you are likely better off creating a single large
> packfile and splitting it using a generic multi-volume archive tool
> (e.g., Unix split).
>
> The minimum size allowed is limited to 1 MiB. The default is
> unlimited. Common unit suffixes of k, m, or g are supported.